# How to communicate with Popen when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Originally, my code is like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    subproc = subprocess.Popen("fem.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    subproc.stdin.write("1\n")
    subproc.stdin.write("1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n")
    subproc.stdin.flush()
    while True:
        line = subproc.stdout.readline()
        print line
```

It calls "fem.exe" as `subproc`, send inputs to `subproc` and get outputs back by a pipe. This code works well.

However, now I need to send some inputs from another thread

```
subproc = subprocess.Popen("fem.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
def run():
    subproc.stdin.write(get_rest_input())
    subproc.stdin.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subproc.stdin.write("1\n")
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run)
    process.start()
    while True:
        line = subproc.stdout.readline()
        print line
```

In this version, I create a new `Process` in which `get_rest_input()` are called to calculate the rest of the inputs `subproc` need. However I got an error from "fem.exe", which told me an EOF error encountered

```
run-time error F6501: READ(CON)
- end of file encountered
```

I just wondering why this happen, is it because I use multiprocessing? If so, why I can't write like this and how to solve this problem?

Comment: you have no reason of using multiprocessing for this. Use multithreading instead you will be able to share the variables. also: never `flush` stdin. If you have nothing else to write, just `close` it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you, now I understand that actually the `subproc` is in two processes, so I can't share them, and when I am trying to pass them as arguments, I got a `pickle` error. Just to ask, is there any walkarounds to this(if I still want to use multiprocessing)? Because I think using multithreading will have a performance loss due to python's GIL

Comment: about threads & performance: that's true for pure python, but you won't lose performance if one of the threads is busy running a command.